# How to binding-data from one page to another page with one controller?

Tags: angularjs, routes

```
'use strict'

var hsbc = angular.module('hsbc',['ngResource','ngRoute']);

hsbc.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){   

    //console.log('config part working'); 
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'hsbccontroller',
            templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html',
            hideMenus: true
        })
        .when('/gloabltranfer', {
            controller: 'hsbccontroller',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/gloabltranfer.html'
        })
        .when('/tranferReq', {
            controller: 'hsbccontroller',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/TransferRquest.html'
        })
        .when('/reviewdetail', {
            controller: 'hsbccontroller',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/Reviewdetails.html'
        })
        .when('/confirmdetail', {
            controller: 'hsbccontroller',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/confirmdetails.html'
        })

        .when('/', {

            templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html'
        })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });

}]).controller('hsbccontroller', ['$scope','$http','$resource','$location', function($scope,$http,$resource,$location, transfer){

    var gformcountry, gtocountry, userID, formData;

    $scope.hsbcaccts = [];
    $scope.countries = [];


    $scope.login = function(){
        var username = $scope.username;
        var pass = $scope.password;
        if(username =='test' && pass =='test'){
            username = 1234;
            $location.path('/gloabltranfer');

        }
        else if(username =='test2' && pass =='test2'){
                username = 2222;
                $location.path('/gloabltranfer');

            }
        else{
                $location.path('/login');
        }
    }
    $http.get('http://localhost/api/Accounts').success(function(data) {
                $scope.hsbcaccts = data.body;
              }).error(function(){
                alert('Sorry server down at moment. please some time later');
              });
     $http.get('http://localhost/api/Country').success(function(data) {
                $scope.countries = data.body;
              }).error(function(){
                alert('Sorry server down at moment. please some time later');
              });

    /*$http.get('json/currency.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.countries = data;
        });*/


    $scope.countryFromTo = function(){
        $scope.fromData ={ 'fromcountry':$scope.fromcountry,'tocountry':$scope.tocountry};
        $location.path('/tranferReq');

    }


    $scope.tranferForm = function(){
        $scope.tranferForm ={ 'fromaccount':$scope.fromaccount,'toaccount':$scope.toaccount, };
        return $scope.tranferForm;
        $location.path('/reviewdetail');
    }

    $scope.reviewdetails = function(){
        //alert($scope.tranferForm);
         $location.path('/confirmdetail');
    }

    $http.get('http://localhost/api/Accounts').success(function(data){
            //alert(data.id);
            $scope.hsbcaccts = data;
    });


}]);
```

Here getting data from ng-click tranferForm  function without submitting data try binding to next page $scope tranferForm function collecting data and display in the page reviewdetail page.
and then my controller twice at a time.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, using same controllers in different pages means two different instances, completely independent of each other.

Now to share the variables between controllers,there are two ways to do this:

1. Store data in factories and fetch from the factories in other page.
2. But a parent controller at body level, or above the view node, and store the values in $scope variables of parent controller. Usually this is on the same html element as the ng-app and is supposed to be the parent of all the controllers.

Plus I think you should be using different controllers.
Putting same controller defeats the purpose of modular programming.

I don't know your case but if possible, create different controllers with different names and put only functions used per page in those controllers.

If there are some functions which are needed in all the places,create a generic function and put it in a service.

Comment: I'm quite new to anugalerjs tried i cant able to make it.

Comment: ok few steps:      1. add ng-controller="appController" to the same element where you have defined ng-app.       2. add a variable object and all values  that you want to share, put them as property of that variable object.

Comment: But still though go through the docs, check this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM, and some egghead.io videos to learn.   Angular doesnt enforce any regulations, so its really important to write proper modular code, its really helpful in the long run